# iOS app does not show images

Tags: feature-request, bug, ios-app

Since a few days, inline images do not show and instead

> enter description here

Text appears. Tapping does not show the image either. (I've included the screenshot here, yet it doesn't show to me!!)

[image]

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 6s Plus
- OS Version: Version 10.3.3 (Build 14G60)

Comment: Shows done for me right now. Probably either a network issue your end or an issue with imgur (try posting an image hosted somewhere other than imgur)

Comment: Could you see the screenshot? I still can't. And I cannot see other images too and that's the problem.

Comment: I've tried imgur.com and I guess it's blocked, cannot be reached. This also explains why I can't see images. Can stackexchange produce a workaround to this problem or shall we wait (a few years?)?

Comment: if imgur is blocked from your end then not much SE can do about that

Comment: SE can take this issue as a feature request, hopefully. Which may bring up interesting new opportunities for them.

Comment: Feature request to do what? Change image hosting? It will just be blocked too. You're using some very strict ISP, that's all.

Comment: Imgur apparently has been blocked not by an isp but by a country and probably not for something that was posted by/for SE. Therefore, SE may think of a workaround for this issue. Though they are not obliged to..

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40656099#40656099

Answer (score 2):

On my iOS I can see your screenshot, please check your iOS, possibly a network error on your side. (proxy, firewall that block content type, etc...)

I see Turkcell as a provider, if in Turkey I know the state often block some site by blocking DNS resolution.

nb; Added my comment as answer to show you my printscreen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this situation arises when and if the image cannot be reached, on the net.

In this particular case, **imgur** (that apparently hosts all images posted on SE) cannot be reached.

Sometimes, some domains are blocked, and most probably **imgur** is currently a blocked web domain.

I don't know how important this issue would be for SE. I've found out that it's not a bug that SE experiences.

However, this can be seen as a feature request to have redundancy of image sources. If one does not load, load the secondary one, or use a different server/domain for people with access issues.